# Tableview subtitle add new line

Tags: xcode, arrays, tableview, xcode4.5, subtitle

I got a tableview with subtitles.
I want to tell the user a bit about the current version of the app.

```
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ver. 0.90", nil]; //App version
tableSubtitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First release contains:/n- Create user/n- Login/n- And so on...", nil]; //What the app can do
```

My problem is that /n don't work.

If anyone knows the way of making a new line, please anwser :)

And by the way i show it like so:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tableSubtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: you should use \n, ... not /n